# subprocess.Popen freezes up

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm using subprocess.Popen to launch an external program with Python.
Specifically Python 2.6 inside Cinema 4D.

It works fine on Windows, but I'm having problems on a mac osx.

```
cmd = ['filepath']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds = False)
pickle.dump(data, p.stdin)
output, error_output = p.communicate()
```

This works repeatedly, until I restart C4D, and then it just freezes everything.  I then need to do 'Force Quit' on the mac.  To reset things so it would work again, I have to delete the directory where the 'filepath' was, and let python throw a file not found error when subprocess.Popen runs.  Once I did this, I could launch my subprocess program repeatedly again, until I restarted C4D again.  Then, the problem returns.

close_fds was set to 'False' because on Windows it needed to be that way for the pipe redirect, but on a mac, maybe it should be set to 'True'.

The problem now is, even if I reboot the computer, 'subprocess.Popen' won't even run from the 'Console' inside C4D.  It just freezes up everything.  Why isn't rebooting resetting everything?  And what should I do to make things work again?

Even this test to throw a file not found error freezes things up.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["test1"])
```

Help!

Comment: On `OS X` I've only ever needed to set `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`. It might help if you could explain a bit more about what you're actually trying to do perhaps.

Comment: What command are you invoking? Is it the same one on Windows and Mac  OS X? It's a little worrying that you are communicating the output of "pickle" to another application.... the pickle format is fine for an application to save/load its own data on a given platform, but the pickle format is not a portable data format.

Comment: cmd is the filepath to an .exe on Windows and an app on OS X.  It is a program I wrote in python that has been packaged by PyInstaller.  The program needs a different version of Python then the one in Cinema 4D.  Pickle is used to to send and receive data through the pipes.  It doesn't need to be portable.  That isn't the problem, and it works fine.  The problem is 'subprocess.Popen' stops working.  Someone suggested it may be a 'file descriptor' issue, but shouldn't rebooting the computer reset all that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After endless hours of testing so the problem could be narrowed down, it now appears that C4D (Cinema 4D) has a bug in it that will freeze up the entire program, including its python 2.6, if you try to use 'subprocess.Popen' and probably other Python commands like 'subprocess.call()' under the following circumstances:  If your plugin contains certain dynlibs, and they are placed with your plugin inside the C4D 'plugins' folder.  They can be placed in a folder next to, or above the 'plugins' folder, but not anywhere nested inside of it.

This problem only appears to exist on the Mac version of C4D.
C4D must be scanning the 'plugins' folder, and getting confused by the presence of dynlibs inside.  This is obviously a bug, as developers should be able to place anything inside their plugin.  It has been reported to Maxon.